# Provide an indicator that your draft is out of date due to edits made after you started it

Tags: feature-request, documentation, edits, documentation-examples

I started editing a popular documentation example, but I didn't have enough time to complete the edit in one sitting, so I saved it as a draft. The next day, I finished editing the example and submitted it for review. My edit was rejected, and then I found out why: another user edited the same documentation example while I was away, so my edit wasn't done on an up-to-date revision of the example (it looked like I reverted the other user's contribution).

**Proposal:**

If a user saves their edit on a documentation example as a draft, and another user edits it while they were away, please notify the user that the example was edited and they're no longer working on an up-to-date version of the example.

> [Another user] edited the example you're working on while you were away. Please check [their changes] to see if you missed anything (or need to merge their edit with yours).

I don't really know if we need this, but maybe we should provide an indicator to reviewers as well:

> [User]'s edit wasn't done on an up-to-date revision of this example due to [edits] made after they started their draft. Please help resolve any conflicts if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. This seems like a completely reasonable proposal. You aren't the first user I've seen bitten by this. I've rejected a couple of proposals and scratched my head about why they rolled back good content. Most likely, they didn't and were just working on a stale draft. If you're going to have a system that *massively* encourages the saving of drafts like Docs does, you need to have a way to sensibly manage merge conflicts. At the very least, implement a poor-man's merge conflict manager: the one between your ears.

Comment: @CodyGray "Notification" for me has a very specific meaning: that's the mailbox thingy at the top of the screen. I can see how some users read the title and though "hell no!" and did not bother reading the actual proposal. I've changed the title to something I think is less likely to send people down the wrong track. (I did think "hell no!" when I saw the title, and then after reading the proposal thought it was a reasonable request.)

Comment: We'd need a `git rebase` functionality for these situations...

Comment: Good call, @Louis! I can definitely see how the original title would provoke that reaction.

Comment: you kind fo expect a merge and a diff wouldnt you ;p i mean it is a coding site

Comment: Yeah, the times I have made changes to active examples I've had to go through the process (description from memory) of submitting the changes, open the review queue in another tab and select my edit to see diffs, then return to editing (in yet another tab) and incorporate the diffs which were changes made by others after the base of my edit. Submit the edit. Repeat the process to verify all constructive prior changes incorporated (or if another change is approved). We *really* need a diff (and merge) capability while editing.

Comment: @ppeterka: Shame git, hg, and bzr haven't been invented yet, right?

Comment: Related question: [Need way to see “my drafts differences”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333594/need-way-to-see-my-drafts-differences)