# A way to see "my drafts differences"

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I've been finding myself clicking links to articles, and then finding I've a draft pending.

This gets me "stuck" in "edit mode" until I either publish or discard the draft.

But there's no way for me to see what changes I've made, if any, because I can only see the "render view" ( [How to navigate out of draft view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329406/how-to-navigate-out-of-draft-view) )

But I don't even know what I changed, or why there's a draft in the first place.

1. I don't wish to delete the draft, because I may have made useful edits and then forgotten about them ( but there's no way for me to see this )
2. I don't want to publish them, because I may have made useless edits and then intended to discard them, but not ( again, no way to see )

So I'm basically stuck with a decision I can't make due to lack of data.

Comment: Related question: [Provide an indicator that your draft is out of date due to edits made after you started it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333445/provide-an-indicator-that-your-draft-is-out-of-date-due-to-edits-made-after-you)

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround to see the diff:

1. Save the draft;
2. go to the dashboard, and copy the URL of the link to your draft (`https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/whatever/drafts/12345`);
3. **[log out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout), or use your browser's private/incognito mode;**
4. go to that URL.